# Cascade delete of multiple member entities of the same type in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created a model of person with two standard addresses and an optional array of additional addresses. All addresses are instances of the same type:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Home { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Office { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Address> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to configure cascade deletion of all addresses associated with person through Fluent API. How to do it?

I tried:

```
builder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(a => a.Locations).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

But it deletes only addresses in array and leaves standard addresses outside of array.

Then I added:

```
builder.Entity<Person>().HasRequired(a => a.Home).WithRequiredDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
builder.Entity<Person>().HasRequired(a => a.Office).WithRequiredDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

and get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table 'Address' may cause cycles
>   or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO
>   ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

What is the correct way to express this rule?

Comment: I know `Home` and `Office` properties looks natural from human view, but from db standpoint `Person` is **dependent**  of `Home` and `Office` `Address` (have FK **to** them), so actually deleting `Address` will try to delete the `Person`. You'd better remove those properties and introduce some sort of a enum property in the `Address` class.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, thank you for reply. I can consider the first address as Home and second as Office, while everything else will belong to other Locations. However, it does not look nice from object domain viewpoint. I m just trying to figure out most elegant way to express this situation in code first model.

Comment: No, you really should use some enum property. What if one day you'll get a homeless person? :)

Comment: @Gert Arnold, thank you. So I should delete separate entries from model and leave only collection. Not entirely along with business logic but natural from DB viewpoint. Fair enough,

Comment: Well, it's just a suggestion. You can use the other two properties if it's more suitable, but yeah, no cascaded delete then.

Comment: Actually, I ve made this model quite a while ago. All worked fine on additions and access until I stumbled this deletion problem. Of course, I felt from beginning that the construct is a bit dubious. So, only one-to-one or one-to-many are standards, never use one-to-two-to-something hybrids. This seems a conclusion.